# Laravel route:list error

Tags: laravel, routes, console

Sometimes when i'm trying to get a route list using console `php artisan route:list` command i get this error:

```
 [ErrorException]
   Trying to get property of non-object
```

then i have to check all my controllers to find the issue source if i were lucky ! . this error doesn't lend me any debug info about where the issue comes from. so how should i resolve it in a large project ?
is there any laravel setting that i should set to get more detailed info ?

Comment: You need to check your logs to get more details about the error. In the `storage/logs`if you're using laravel 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try versose mode on the command

It will give you more information about the error

```
php artisan route:list -v
```

Comment: using `\Request->user()->id` was the problem. if i change it to `\Auth::id()` the issue will resolve. but whats wrong with `Request` facade?

Comment: @alex Are you trying to get the id of the logged in user?

Comment: When you run an artisan command you're not logged in (unless you've built that in yourself) so the `Request::user()` will return `null` which in turn causes `Trying to get property of non-object` because you try to access the property `id` on `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Debug the error by turning on verbose error reporting: `php artisan route:list -v`.

There could be some error in your `Controller` or in your `router`

Make sure that controller is not calling any incorrect type on an eloquent query.